# Deleting Buckets in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have followed the directions provided by Google to delete some old buckets in the in my account ... it is very straight forward process listed however after confirming the deletion to occur the "Preparing  to Delete" pops up on the bottom left, but the system never deletes the files and bucket ?

I have posted this several times but no one have suggested a solution or a reason why the process does not work.

Comment: I just figured out what was happening (I think) ... I attempted to delete the buckets again, and just left the screen as it was and after 1.5 hours it actually did delete the bucket. It takes a lot longer than I had expected.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a lot of files in your bucket, it might simply take a long time to perform the operation.

As a workaround to the UI being unclear, you can [use gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm) to remove all files in a bucket, followed by the bucket itself, using `gsutil rm -r gs://bucket`.

Comment: Use -m for parallel delete "gsutil rm -m gs://bucket"

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, when the bucket has lots of objects, using the web interface or gsutil alone is not the best way.

What I did, was that I added a life cycle rule, to have Google delete all the object in the bucket.

[image: Add lifecycle rule under the "Bucket Lock" tab]

[image: Now have Google delete objects]

Then, coming back after a day, the bucket can easily be deleted.

Comment: Do you know, is it possible to delete bucket, instead of files in the bucket (another words - bucket and files in bucket)?

Comment: It's been a while, so I don't know if this is possible now. But at the time, it wasn't possible to easily delete buckets with a lot of objects in them.

But may [Indradeet Gours comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253399/deleting-buckets-in-google-cloud-storage/56390393?noredirect=1#comment95481625_48254290) makes this possible?