# Problems deleting GCP storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have two buckets that I can't delete on GCP, tried through the UI. I can't find any support info from GCP and can't delete them. They are relatively large and I want to avoid the cost as well. Do I need to delete the project?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deleting Buckets in Google Cloud Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48253399/deleting-buckets-in-google-cloud-storage)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [previously posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48253399/7395911), this process may actually take a while, so perhaps just wait a little bit.

But, if it still doesn't work than perhaps you can follow what was suggested.

> As a workaround to the UI being unclear, you can use [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rm) to remove all files in a bucket, followed by the bucket itself, using `gsutil rm -r gs://bucket`.

Or perhaps `gsutil rm -m gs://bucket` for a parallel deletion.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete GCP bucket using UI (Check you have access to delete GCP bucket )

Otherwise, you can delete the GCP bucket using gsutil

// Set Project name

```
gcloud config set project <Project_Name>
```

// Delete Bucket

```
gsutil rm -m gs://<Bucket-Name>
```